# Magento overriding block makes block disappear

Tags: magento

So I am overriding a block that adds some tabs. All I am trying to do is remove a couple of the tabs. However, even though die() in my code kills everything (so it IS being called) I am getting a blank spot where the tabs used to be. Here is the code:

config.xml:

```
<global>
        <blocks>
            <affiliateplusext>
                <class>Blizzardlabs_Affiliateplusext_Block</class>
            </affiliateplusext>                
            <affiliateplusstatistic>
                <rewrite>
                    <frontend_diagrams>Blizzardlabs_Affiliateplusext_Block_Frontend_Diagrams</frontend_diagrams>
                </rewrite>
            </affiliateplusstatistic>
        </blocks>
</global>
```

THEIR layout file:

```
class Magestore_Affiliateplusstatistic_Block_Frontend_Diagrams extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tabs
{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setId('diagram_tab');
        $this->setDestElementId('diagram_tab_content');
        $this->setTemplate('affiliateplusstatistic/widget/tabshoriz.phtml');
    }

    protected function _prepareLayout(){
        $this->addTab('sales',array(
            'label'     => $this->__('Sales Amount'),
            'content'   => $this->getLayout()->createBlock('affiliateplusstatistic/frontend_diagrams_sales')->toHtml(),
            //'active'  => true,
        ));

        $this->addTab('transactions',array(
            'label'     => $this->__('Transactions'),
            'content'   => $this->getLayout()->createBlock('affiliateplusstatistic/frontend_diagrams_transactions')->toHtml(),
        ));

        $this->addTab('commissions',array(
            'label'     => $this->__('Commissions'),
            'content'   => $this->getLayout()->createBlock('affiliateplusstatistic/frontend_diagrams_commissions')->toHtml(),
        ));

        $this->addTab('clicks',array(
            'label'     => $this->__('Clicks'),
            'content'   => $this->getLayout()->createBlock('affiliateplusstatistic/frontend_diagrams_clicks')->toHtml(),
        ));

        $this->addTab('impressions',array(
            'label'     => $this->__('Impressions'),
            'content'   => $this->getLayout()->createBlock('affiliateplusstatistic/frontend_diagrams_impressions')->toHtml(),
        ));

        $this->setChild('totals',$this->getLayout()->createBlock('affiliateplusstatistic/frontend_diagrams_totals'));
        $this->setChild('filters',$this->getLayout()->createBlock('affiliateplusstatistic/frontend_filters'));

        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }
}
```

My layout file:

```
<?php
class Blizzardlabs_Affiliateplusext_Block_Frontend_Diagrams extends Magestore_Affiliateplusstatistic_Block_Frontend_Diagrams
{
    protected function _prepareLayout(){
        $this->addTab('sales',array(
            'label'     => $this->__('Sales Amount'),
            'content'   => $this->getLayout()->createBlock('affiliateplusstatistic/frontend_diagrams_sales')->toHtml(),
            'active'    => true,
        ));
//      
//      $this->addTab('transactions',array(
//          'label'     => $this->__('Transactions'),
//          'content'   => $this->getLayout()->createBlock('affiliateplusstatistic/frontend_diagrams_transactions')->toHtml(),
//      ));
//      
//      $this->addTab('commissions',array(
//          'label'     => $this->__('Commissions'),
//          'content'   => $this->getLayout()->createBlock('affiliateplusstatistic/frontend_diagrams_commissions')->toHtml(),
//      ));
//      
//
//        
//        $this->setChild('totals',$this->getLayout()->createBlock('affiliateplusstatistic/frontend_diagrams_totals'));
//        $this->setChild('filters',$this->getLayout()->createBlock('affiliateplusstatistic/frontend_filters'));

        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }
}
```

there are no errors or logs. Please help!

Comment: Where are you putting your `die`/`exit`?

Comment: I have put the die() in my override of _prepareLayout(). Its not there now but when I do put it in it die's successfully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about the order of operations with the layout xml.. But i know i've removed tabs on other modules from my local.xml in the design folder like this:

```
<module_controller_action> <!-- **(Direct accordingly) -->
    <reference name="the_specific_tabs_block_name">
        <action method="removeTab"><name>transactions</name></action>
    </reference>
</module_controller_action>
```

Way better than making a class and extending the original. (if it works)

Good luck.

Comment: Here is the problem. We have tried doing just exactly that. However, as they are adding tabs through _prepareLayout override I have to stick with my method. This is because their method is called after the layout is instantiated. So if I were to use this method I would be trying to remove a tab that doesn't exist yet.

Comment: that's what i figured. You probably shouldn't comment out the `setChild()` parts at the bottom there. Could be your problem.

Comment: Marshall you hit the nail on the head. Obviously if I am overriding their code and don't have the `setChild()` parts their then the blocks arent available to the layout....i feel dumb. Thank you!